# Is there a more up-to-date version of this TDD/DDD NAnt development I should be reading instead?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, domain-driven-design, nant

I'm reading [this tutorial](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/NAntStarterSeries.aspx) on NAnt development in C# .NET, it was written in 2006, so I'm wondering if anyone knew there is a more up-to-date version that I ought to read instead.

The [tutorial](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/NAntStarterSeries.aspx) called "Automating Your Builds With NAnt" covers setting up a project with unit testing, domain driven development, integration with Visual Studio etc...

Comment: @Arnis Does it work with .net?  It's looks like a Java / Linux CI from the site.

Comment: it does work. using it successfully. mix in albacore and You are golden.

Comment: @Arnis Have you used CruiseControl in the past prior to this?  If so what are the advantages?

Comment: i prefer Hudson over CC. CC is quite hard to configure in my opinion. antoher alternative - Bamboo, but it's commercial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is restricted to NAnt, J.P. Boodhoo's tutorial provides an excellent overview on how to get your NAnt environment to productivity quickly. Don't bother it's from 2006 because the NAnt framework hasn't changed too much since.

If you're considering to use a more fancy build environment, then you might want to take a look at [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/), [psake](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake) or even [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) (is this more fancy?). We still use NAnt because it has proven 100% sufficient to our needs.

If you would like to do the whole TDD thing, Continuous Integration is the next thing to add to your build environment. [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), [CruiseControl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/), [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)/[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) are all good choices for that. Either they target CI for .NET explicitly (like CCNET or TeamCity) or they can be easily configured to do so.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that for me!  I'm an ANT user from back in about 2005 and my new job uses NANT.  I had a hunch it was the right tutorial but I wasn't completely sure (mainly cause it was from 2006...) glad to hear not much has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these books are more recent and up to date:

1. [Continuous Integration in .NET](http://www.manning.com/kawalerowicz/) (2011)

   - I'm pretty sure this book has a lot of helpful things to know about continuous integration. I haven't gotten around to reading it yet, so I can't comment much about it though.
2. [Brownfield Application Development
   in .NET](http://www.manning.com/baley/) (2010)

   - Around page 69 it starts talking about NAnt. Throughout the book it touches on TDD. Note though the book is geared towards adding these techniques and tools to existing projects, not greenfield.